# WPF : How to animate a button on click of another button?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Menu 1" Height="23" Name="button1" Width="75" Margin="10">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="0" To="200" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```

This code moves the button in the Y direction when the mouse is over the button.
However, I want the same functionality when I move my mouse over another button.
In short, let's assume I have Button1 and Button2. When I move my mouse over Button1, the Button2 should move down in the Y direction. How can I achieve this. Could anyone provide a working XAML code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass Button and add a property named ButtonToAnimate.

In the event trigger, point the Target of the DoubleAnimation to the ButtonToAnimate.